# Copy files along with file paths from a list to a folder or another path

Tags: python, copy, shutil

I have a list containing files along with their paths. I need to copy or move the files with their entire path into another directory or folder.

I have tried as follows but path unable to copy the path and only files are being copied.

```
import shutil
list_l1 = ['/home/Test//A/Aa/hello1.c', '/home/Test/C/Aa/hello1.c', '/home/Test/B/Aa/hello1.c']
for source in list_l1:
    shutil.move(source, '/home/Test/sample_try/sample/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `os.makedirs()` to make the nested directories. You might want to separate the paths in your `list_l1` into directory and filename parts first, and use `os.path.exists()` to check if the directory exists before attempting to create it.

You could try:

```
import shutil
import os

list_l1 = ['/home/Test//A/Aa/hello1.c', '/home/Test/C/Aa/hello1.c', '/home/Test/B/Aa/hello1.c']
dest = '/home/Test/sample_try/sample'
for source in list_l1:
    dirname, filename = os.path.split(source)
    if not os.path.exists(f'{dest}/{dirname}'):
        os.makedirs(f'{dest}/{dirname}')
    shutil.copy(source, f'{dest}/{source}')
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to python as i'm not aware of all the modules. Could you brief or provide me with sample snippet?

Comment: File "sme1.py", line 8
    if not os.path.exists(f'{dest}/{dirname}'):
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What version of python are you using? In my answer I am using f-strings which require at least python 3.6. If you are using python < 3.6, you will just have to concatenate strings with + operation instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making the directories first like below or some other library.

```
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

list_l1 = ['./A/Aa/hello1.c', './B/Aa/hello1.c']
new_parent = './C'

for source in list_l1:
    path_list = source.split('/')
    file = path_list.pop()
    new_path = path_list.pop(0)
    dirs = '/'.join(path_list)
    p = new_parent + '/' + dirs  + '/'
    path = Path(p)
    path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    shutil.move(source, p)
```

Comment: using `os.makedirs()` as described in my earlier answer is rather more concise.

Comment: You are right @jamesoh . I just thought that this could be give another options.